# Can we prepare latex document for Perfect binding?

Tags: binding

How to make huge number of pages to prepare for 
Perfect binding in latex I got from from internet about perfect binding 
Perfect binding is commonly used for catalogs, directories and paperback books that have a higher page count. Pages are glued together at the spine with a strong, flexible glue. The cover is wrapped around the glued pages, and the brochure or catalog is then trimmed to its finished size.
As for example if we look at the books of "The LaTeX Companion" the total page is 1120, then normal binding may not be feasible to make the hard binding, so in that case perfect binding will choose to make the hard binding of the required book. I don't have much idea about binding. As far as my concern each consist of bundle of sheets and each sheet contain two pages on one side and two  pages on another side of different page numbering. Thanking you in advance.

[image]

Comment: Your question is truly insufficient.  However, if you are referring to the notion that binding eats up paper margin, LaTeX provides the lengths `\oddsidemargin` and `\evensidemargin` that can be used to shift page text right/left to allow for binding distance.

Comment: Besides this the package `geometry` knows the option bindingoffset. And the fine KOMAscript classes offer the BCOR-option.

Comment: I assume you mean the form of binding as described eg https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookbinding#Thermally_activated_binding but it isn't clear what your latex question is, that form means you do not lose much on the binding edge but the other three edges may be trimmed by an amount depending on the printer and exact process, in any case the geometry package or koma classes can specify the type area on the page, it isn't clear what other aspects of the binding process are related to latex.

Comment: @ Biki Teron: I am sorry, but I still can not see where the relevance to LaTeX is given.

Comment: Making signatures and binding signatures to books isn't a TeX problem but a the skill of the cooperation of the printer and the bookbinder.

Comment: The "mass-market paperback" form described on the wikipedia page @DavidCarlisle linked would appear to be compatible with a `twoside` document without any extra effort - "made with each sheet fully cut and glued at the spine" says that page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word you need to know: imposition.

Imposition is the arrangement of pages on a piece of paper, so that they are in the correct places when the paper is cut and folded.

For example, a perfect bound 5.5in x 8.5in book might have 4 pages printed, double-side, on 8.5in x 11in paper. One side of the paper will have pages 1 and 4, each oriented sideways. The other side of the paper will have pages 2 and 3. When folded, the order becomes 1, 2, 3, 4.  This must be done for every group of four pages.

That is not a job for TeX. Doing it with TeX is theoretically possible, but would require a great deal of manual coding. It is a job for professional PDF software, intended for print production. You could probably do it in Adobe Reader, four pages at a time.

But that is all way beyond the scope of TeX.

And, I DO know how Perfect Binding works.

Edit: In view of following comments and answer, I note: When I wrote my original reply (above), I assumed that the OP was trying to obtain a book size that was essentially half the size of the unfolded paper. That's a common technique for do-it-yourself books where I live. But it is not applicable to every size book and paper. The actual situation could be simpler (if book size is paper size) or much more complicated (commercial press).

Comment: You can do the imposition with pdftk and a script.

Comment: @ChrisH Yes, I believe so.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert on binding techniques (I have but dabbled so far), so if I have misunderstood the problem, I apologize. But since it hasn't been mentioned yet: You can create signatures with the `pdfpages` package.

I have two documents:

```
.
├── child.tex
└── Main.tex
```

### Child Document

`child.tex` contains your actual content. In this case, it is a simple `article` with the `twoside` option and some dummy text:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\section{First Page}
\lipsum[1]
\clearpage\section{Second Page}
\lipsum[2]
\clearpage\section{Third Page}
\lipsum[3]
\clearpage\section{Fourth Page}
\lipsum[4]
\clearpage\section{Fifth Page}
\lipsum[5]
\clearpage\section{Sixth Page}
\lipsum[6]
\clearpage\section{Seventh Page}
\lipsum[7]
\clearpage\section{Eighth Page}
\lipsum[8]
\clearpage\section{Ninth Page}
\lipsum[9]
\clearpage\section{Tenth Page}
\lipsum[10]
\clearpage\section{Eleventh Page}
\lipsum[11]
\clearpage\section{Twelfth Page}
\lipsum[12]
\clearpage\section{Thirteenth Page}
\lipsum[13]
\clearpage\section{Fourteenth Page}
\lipsum[14]
\clearpage\section{Fifteenth Page}
\lipsum[15]
\clearpage\section{Sixteenth Page}
\lipsum[16]
\clearpage\section{Seventeenth Page}
\lipsum[17]
\end{document}
```

After compiling `child.tex`, `child.pdf` can be included in `Main.tex` and signatures of the desired size can be created (in this case 8 pages, resulting in two sheets of paper per signature):

### Main Document

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[landscape,a3paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=-,signature=8]{child.pdf}
\end{document}
```

The result can be printed double-side over the long edge. Note that empty pages will be inserted at the end if necessary to fill an entire signature (in this case, seven pages, leading to three additional sheets of paper).

I have used this technique a few times since creating booklets and signatures on Linux is a bit of a pain (just google the topic and you will get a lot of hits, many of which leading to rather cumbersome solutions, at least in my humble opinion). I used to use Acrobat Reader, but its Linux version was no longer maintained last I checked. This approach has worked quite well for me so far.

### EDIT: Result, First Signature

Page 1 of `Main.pdf` (on first physical sheet): Contains Pages 1 and 8 of `child.pdf`:
[image: first sheet, front side]
Page 2 of `Main.pdf` (on first physical sheet): Contains pages 2 and 7 of `child.pdf`:
[image: first sheet, back side]
Page 3 of `Main.pdf` (on second physical sheet): Contains pages 3 and 6 of `child.pdf`:
[image: second sheet, front side]
Page 4 of `Main.pdf` (on second physical sheet): Contains pages 4 and 5 of `child.pdf`:
[image: second sheet, back side]

Comment: Indeed. But Perfect Binding usually involves two pages per side of physical paper, folded. However, if the size of the book is the size of the paper (or you are willing to trim every piece of paper) then it can be done the way you described.

Comment: @RobtA Okay, now you got me slightly confused: "two pages per side" is what my result looks like to me (I have edited the post to add some pictures of the result). It puts two A4 pages on each A3 page, for a total of 4 A4 pages per sheet of of physical A3 paper. You fold the A3 sheet in the middle and have a signature, or not (I have even printed it out just to be sure that it works)? I reckon I am misunderstanding something related to the terminology here. Apologies for being an ignoramus, and thank you for your patience.

Comment: Of course, if you print this on something larger than A3 without scaling, yes, you'd need to trim, that I get, yes.

Comment: A3-A4 situation: That is similar to halving US Letter paper to get 5.5"x8.5". Side 1 of A3: At top (rotated counter-clockwise) page 1. Bottom half: rotated counter-clockwise page 4. Side 2 of A3, flipped at left long edge: Top half, rotated clockwise page 2. Bottom half: rotated clockwise page 3. Now do this for each group of four pages. Only for home use, not commercial printing. But folding each sheet precisely, so that the pages all line up at the edges, is very hard to do. And, you must clamp at the spine and shave off the folds before gluing. Do-able with skill and tools. Difficult.

Comment: Yes, I wouldn't expect stuff to be printed out at home to work the same as commercial printing, makes sense. I have done book-binding at home (I actually have a self-bound copy of `memman.pdf`), though I used case binding, not perfect binding, and that's pretty easy to do for A4 pages with A3 paper (or A5 on A4). That's probably also why home-binding was what first came to mind when reading OP's question; I wouldn't expect this to be intended for the commercial press, because in that case it's not my problem as an author, it's the printer's. Thank you for your elaborations.